# subclassing PhoneApplicationPage is not calling the inherited methods

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, inheritance

I have created a Base class like this:

```
`namespace XXX.Screens
{
    public partial class Settings_screen_BASE : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public static readonly bool DEBUG = true;

        public Settings_screen_BASE()
        {
            if (DEBUG)
                Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType() + "->" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            InitializeComponent();
            if (DEBUG)
                Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType() + "<-" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }
    }
}`
```

And this child class:

```
 namespace XXX.Screens
{
    public partial class Settings_screen_Child : Settings_screen_BASE
    {

        public Settings_screen_Child()
        {

            if (DEBUG)
                Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType() + "->" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            base.InitializeComponent();
            if (DEBUG)
                Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType() + "<-" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I now call:

```
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Screens/Settings_screen_BASE.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

It works well,

but when I call

```
  this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Screens/Settings_screen_Child.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I just get a black screen and the debug output does not show any creation of the child class.

Can you please tell me what I am missing here?

I would have expected that calling the child would do exactly the same as calling the base class.
At least it should call `Settings_screen_Child()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going on.  You should make sure that you are referencing the proper base class in the in the child page.  I created my own version of your example, and it seems to be working fine for me.  You can check out my sample project here : http://sdrv.ms/XLcyvR

Comment: absolutely perfect what I needed - thank you very much for your effort!