# Passing data between user and server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to transfer data from the user to the server an back through restsharp. Below is the code that i have used. I am receiving an error that "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context"

How do i debug this? Is there any logical error?

```
'using System;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Documents;
 using System.Windows.Ink;
 using System.Windows.Input;
 using System.Windows.Media;
 using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
 using System.Windows.Shapes;
 using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
 using RestSharp;
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;


 namespace Miser_sApp
 {
     public class RestSharp
     {
         public partial class SearchResults : PhoneApplicationPage
         {
             public static float _latitude, _longitude;
             public static DateTime _date, _time;
             public static string _name, _details;
             public static int _number, _amount, _uid;
             RestClient client;
             RestRequest request;

             int index;
             connect Connect;
             public SearchResults()
             {
                 InitializeComponent();
                 load();

             }
             private RestClient InitializeX()
             {
                 var client = new RestClient("//localhost" + Panorama1.username1 +                "&pro_type=" + Panorama1.number1 + "&pro_name=" + Panorama1.details1 + "&lat=" + Panorama1.lat1 + "&lon=" + Panorama1.lon1);
                 return client;
                 // request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
             }
             public void load()
             {
                 client = InitializeX();
                 //MessageBox.Show("InternalInitialize Done");
                 request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

                 client.ExecuteAsync<connect>(request, (response) =>
                 {
                     //   MessageBox.Show(response.Data.ToString());
                     Connect = response.Data;
                     if (response.Data == null || Connect.last == null || Connect == null)
                     {
                         MessageBox.Show("NO ITEMS FOUND");
                         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Personal.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

                     }
                     // name1.Items.Add(rootObject3.Details[0].ProductName);
                     //results.Items.Clear();
                     //int i = 0;
                     else
                         foreach (var row3 in Connect.last)
                         {
                             results.Items.Add("NAME-" + row3.Name + '\n' + "Details-" + row3.Details + '\n' + "Date-" + row3.Date + '\n' + "Amount-" + row3.Amount + '\n' + "userId-" + row3.Uid + '\n' + "---------------------------------------------------------------");
                         }
                 });

             }




             private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
             {

                 Konnect d = Connect.last[index];
                 _name = d.Name;
                 _date = d.Date;
                 _time = d.Time;
                 _uid = d.Uid;
                 _amount = d.Amount;
                 _details = d.Details;
                 _latitude = d.Latitude;
                 _longitude = d.Longitude;

                 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Panaroma1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));


             }

             private void results_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
             {
                 index = results.SelectedIndex;
             }

         }
         public class Konnect
         {
             public string Name { get; set; }
             public DateTime Date { get; set; }
             public DateTime Time { get; set; }
             public int Uid { get; set; }
             public String Details { get; set; }
             public int Amount { get; set; }
             public float Latitude { get; set; }
             public float Longitude { get; set; }
         }

         public class connect
         {
             public List<Konnect> last { get; set; }
         }

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the InitializeComponent(); Method does not exist. in the code below. This might be a reference problem. It could also mean there is something wrong with the designer file as it is needed for Designer Support. You can try stepping into that method when you run you debugger. Also where does the error Occur? Is it a run time error or does it happen when you try to compile? If it's a compile error it means that the method does not exist and you either need to create it or remove the reference of it in that method.

```
public SearchResults()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    load();

}
```

EDIT:

Your are possibly missing this part in the designer.cs file. Note this is based of an win form application. You will need to research where this method sits for the class you are trying to inherit from. i.e. PhoneApplicationPage class

```
    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Text = "Form1";
    }
    #endregion
```

I just created a new app and it automatically generated this for me. You must of deleted it or something.

Comment: the error occurs during compilation. What do you mean by method does not exist? This is created by Visual Studio itself when we create a new class.

Comment: This means there is something wrong with the .designer.cs file or something. Your right visual studio generates that method for you. What I can suggest is create a new app and have a look under the .designer.cs file ther will be a method. Look at my edit above.

Comment: Where is designer.cs file located?

Comment: Im not sure where it will sit for the Class you are inheriting from. I think it is in the base class. So this comes back to my theory of it being a referencing problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809699/subclassing-phoneapplicationpage-is-not-calling-the-inherited-methods
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074654/inheriting-code-behind-class-from-phoneapplicationpages-subclass